# Run IPython Notebook in Iframe from another Domain

Tags: iframe, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to run an IPython notebook that is on my server inside an iframe on another server. 
I get this error:

```
Refused to display 'my_url/Test.ipynb' in a frame because 
it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

Here it says I should set some x-frame-header option for this:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/whatsnew/development.html#iframe-embedding

Where can I set this? How to change this X-Frame-Option so that it can be embedded from another site? :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

According to the answer by @simon (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358222/1469195), you should nowadays add the following to the ipython_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors https://mywebsite.example.com 'self' "
    }
}
```

(see  https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#embedding-the-notebook-in-another-website)

**Prior Update**

according to the comment by  Harrison, it should be

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {'headers': {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/'}}
```

now, see also http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

**Original Post**

Ok I found a solution that is working but I am not 100% sure if it is the right way to do it:
In *.ipython/your_profile/ipython_notebook_config.py* add

```
c.NotebookApp.webapp_settings = {'headers': {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/'}}
```

Works for me, but not sure if this overrides more settings from tornado or anything :)

Comment: `webapp_settings` is now deprecated.  Instead use `tornado_settings`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with `webapp_settings` and `webapp_settings`.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer use this so don't know what could be the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried and the answer doesn't work now.
The sugestion in the https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#embedding-the-notebook-in-another-website work for me.
Add the following to the ipython_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors https://mywebsite.example.com 'self' "
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

an easy way is to use the "cell magic" `%%html` to embed an iframe into jupyter cell

example:

```py
%%html
<iframe width="500" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vTingdk_pVM" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, please note that I wanted to run the notebook inside an iframe on another server, not run an iframe inside the notebook.